# How to deploy EAR in WebSphere Application Server using Jython script?

Tags: websphere, jython, ear, websphere-8, wsadmin

How to deploy application in WebSphere Application Server using Jython script? What is happening during ear file deployment?. Could you please explain it step by step?

Comment: What is your problem, you have to explain it a bit more. Which version are you using? You want to deploy via admin console (easiest) or Jython script?

Comment: i have to preapre a jython script for ear deployment , which of the        points have to take consideration for this process, (i am using WAS8.5 verstion).

Answer (score 3):

The shortest form of the script would be:

```
AdminApp.install('fullpath/yourApp.ear', ['-MapWebModToVH', [['.*', '.*', 'default_host']]])
AdminConfig.save()
```

During the process application is validated, uploaded to the server and expanded (by default in the `installeApps` folder. `AdminConfig.save()` commits the changes done by the script. If you want just to test the script, you can call `AdminConfig.reset()` to discard any changes.

See documentation for all the details and options:

- [Installing enterprise applications using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html?lang=en)
- [Options for the AdminApp](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html?lang=en)